# Running a Thread inside Anonymous action Listener?

Tags: java

i know how to implement thread using `Runnable` class, but I am having issues implementing it when my Network task is executed from inside the anonymous class of Action listener.

Conside this code which is inside a class implementing `ActionListener`

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    ...
    b1 = new JButton("OK");
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MySocket sock1 = new SMTPSocket(s1.getText(),fromField.getText(),subjectField.getText());
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

Now, i want to run this code,

```
MySocket sock1 = new SMTPSocket(s1.getText(),fromField.getText(),subjectField.getText());
```

in a Thread but since it is executed from the anonymous class of a actionlistener, how Am i suppose to execute it in a thread ?

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate what you would like to achieve with your program? It might be that your design needs to be reviewed.

Comment: I want to send an email when the button is pressed, and when I press the button the instance of class `mySocket` is created and it send the email, but i want to create the instance of MySocket class inside thread so that the email is sent inside a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a method called `startThread` and call this method on buttn click listener

and in that method write a thread which will execute your code..

try this..

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            startThread();
        } 
    }
});
```

and `startThread` method will be like this..

```
private void startThread() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
             MySocket sock1 = new SMTPSocket(s1.getText(),fromField.getText(),subjectField.getText());
        }
    }.start();

}
```